# Custom Node images for neo4j visualization?

Tags: neo4j, visualization

I need an open-source solution for visualizing a neo4j graph in a web application.  I'm looking at alchemy.js, and it seems pretty cool.  What I'd ultimately like to do is use icons for different node types, instead of just different colors.  Is there a way to do that with alchemy.js?  If so, how?  If not, is there a different *open-source* toolkit that would enable this?  Obviously, KeyLines does it, but it's far from open-source.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can also check out [linkurious.js](https://github.com/Linkurious/linkurious.js) which is open source, based on sigma.js and afaik has customizable images.

Comment: Cool, thanks!  I was confused because there is also a for-fee linkurious.

Comment: @MichaelHunger Do you know if there are plans to support this functionality via the neo browser at some stage?

Comment: I guess the webadmin tool supports it: https://vimeo.com/58016492 . Worked for me, it would just be nice if you could import your visualization profiles to the 'main' browser.

Comment: It's definitely planned to make them en-par for Neo4j 3.0